# state is updated but unable to display the item in react todo app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to display the updated list on adding new item to the list. I tried console logging the state and found that state has new user added to the list but item is not shown in the list. I have dummy data in this app so list is on localstorage. I tried console log at each function to trace out the reason but only dummy data was displayed each time and on adding new user a blank `<li>` block was displayed

Below is the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
    import './style.css';

    class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          names: [
            { name: 'Joel', id: 1 },
            { name: 'Alena', id: 2 },
            { name: 'Andrew', id: 3 },
            { name: 'Harry', id: 4 },
            { name: 'Ron', id: 5 },
          ],
          newName: ''
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.submitHandle = this.submitHandle.bind(this);
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        console.log(this.state.names)
      }

      handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({ newName: e.target.value }, () => {
          console.log(this.state.newName)
        });
      }

      submitHandle(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ names: [...this.state.names, this.state.newName] },
          () => {
            console.log(this.state.names)
          })
      }

      render() {
        const { names } = this.state;
        let list = names.map((user) =>
          <li key={user.id} className="list-group-item">
            {user.name}
          </li>
        )

        return (
          <div className="container">
            <br />
            <div>
              <form onSubmit={this.submitHandle} className="input-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Invite Someone"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.newName}
                  onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <span className="input-group-btn">
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </span>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div className="jumbotron ">
              <ul className="list-group">
                {list}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Check your data structure which are present in the state and you are updating. Both are different, both should be array. Also take care of `id` in the array object.

Comment: Ya looking into it. Can you tell  whats the correct format for id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used an array of objects. So you need to define the exact object before concatenate with the `array`. Please find the code below with the updated change

```
this.setState(
  { names: [...this.state.names, { name: this.state.newName }] },
  () => {
    console.log(this.state.names);
  }
);
```